# How to cope with noise in the background?

Tags: l2-acquisition, listening

I find that my ability to understand speech deteriorates rapidly when there is noise in the background. The effect seems to be more pronounced the weaker the language is for me - English is fine even with noise, while Scandinavian languages get very hard to understand with even little noise, for me. And with my native language the problems only appear when the noise overwhelms the speech.

Is there a way of practicing this, aside from just listening more of the language and becoming more fluent?